# How to check/test whether application is not caching on browser?

Tags: java, spring, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I have written a `class CacheControlFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter`
to set header to make sure that the application is not caching. have done entry in the web.xml also

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name> Cache controller filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Cache controller filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

please suggest me how to check/test whether this is working or not?
let me know if you want more information about the same.

Comment: Use browsers dev tools(F12) and check the HTTP status code it should be 200 not 304.

Comment: 200 for no cache and 304 for caching , am i right?

Comment: Yes, `200 OK` Standard responce and `304 Not Modified` the resource is not changed so fetch it from cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use browsers inspection tools(<kbd>F12</kbd>) and then check the resource's HTTP status code it should be `200 OK` instead of `304 Not Modified` then the resource is not cached.

The below screenshots are Google Chrome examples.

**Cached version of welcome.html**

[image]

Status Code is `304 Not Modified`

**Non cached version of welcome.html**

[image]

Status Code is `200 OK`